# ddev start getting stuck on Pulling web (drud/ddev-webserver:v1.4.0)

Tags: ddev

After upgrading to 1.4.0, I can't start any projects. I get the following:

```
Starting project_name...
Pulling web (drud/ddev-webserver:v1.4.0)...
```

And it just gets stuck there.

I've already tried re-running `ddev config`

Comment: That is a big download, luckily it's a one-time affair, but it's nearing half a gigabyte. Please wait longer. For more feedback, do `docker pull drud/ddev-webserver:v1.4.0`

Comment: That worked, thanks!